# Наречие, краткое прилагательное или предикатив?

Tags: прилагательные, наречия, части-речи

*Это **хорошо**.*

*Это **плохо**.*

*Это **больно**.*

*Здоровье **неважно**.*

*Всё оказалось **отлично**.*

Какими частями речи являются слова, выделенные жирным, — наречиями, краткими прилагательными или предикативами (словами категории состояния)?

Answer (score 1):

Все предложения двусоставные, во всех случаях мы имеем составное именное сказуемое, связка пропущена, **именная часть выражена кратким прилагательным** (отвечает на вопрос *каково*).

**Почему это не наречие?** Наречие может быть именной частью, если это не качественное наречие, соотнесенное по форме с кратким прилагательным, например: *Сосед навеселе. Он с ними заодно. Сестра замужем. Здесь всё по-другому.*

**Но, может быть, это предикатив?** Не, это не он. Предикатив — это **безлично-предикативное слово,** которое относится к словам категории состояния, а в приведенных примерах предложения двусоставные. В случае предикатива субъект состояния присутствует, но он выражен косвенными падежами.

*На улице тепло. Детям стало страшно. Со здоровьем у него неважно. Ему больно.*

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "именной связкой"? Может быть, "именная часть"? И поясните, пожалуйста, почему только качественное наречие может выступать в качестве сказуемого?

Comment: Да, конечно, именная часть. Ответ исправлен.

Comment: Ударение в краткой форме форме среднего рода прилагательного "больной" на последнем слоге — *больно́*. А у нас *бо́льно*. Может, всё‑таки наречие?

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, почему качественное наречие не может выступать в качестве сказуемого?

Comment: Все три предложения с "это" похожи и вызывают у меня сомнение, тут дело даже не в ударении. По семантике слова   "хорошо, плохо, больно"  выражают состояние. Это относится к ситуации, которую можно назвать различным образом, например: Завтра опять дождь. - Это плохо. Плохо, что завтра опять дождь.  Надо смазать царапину йодом. - Мазать йодом - это больно.  Пожалуй, я затрудняюсь с ответом, надо искать в источнике. Мне такое предложение кажется неполным с точки зрения семантики, так как оно связано с предыдущим текстом и указывает не на предмет, а на ситуацию.

Comment: Всё-таки я считаю, что эти слова - КРАТКИЕ ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫЕ, отнесенные к предмету в двусоставном предложении. А предметом здесь является сама ситуация, обозначенная указательным местоимением. Сравним: Игра в мяч - веселая (какая). Играть в мяч весело (каково).  Это весело (каково) - играть в мяч.  Здесь оценивается сама игра как предмет, который может обозначаться существительным, инфинитивом, указательным местоимением. Что касается ударения в кратком прилагательном бОльно, то я думаю, что это частный случай со смещением ударения на основу.

Answer (score 1):

`Это (каково?) хорошо.`

`Это (каково?) плохо.`

`Это (каково?) больно.`

`Здоровье (каково?) неважно.`

`Всё оказалось (каково?) отлично.`

**Краткие прилагательные.** Они выражены сказуемыми. Поэтому они не наречия, т. к. они были бы обстоятельствами, а они сказуемые. И это не предикатив, т. к. есть подлежащее.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, это наречия (или если угодно предикативные наречия). [См учебники](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/704-15_sostavnoe_imennoe_skazuemoe.html) :

> Жизнь – это хорошо.
> Хорошо – составное именное сказуемое. Именная часть выражена наречием

[и](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/706-17_tire_mezhdu_podlezhaschim_i_skazuemym.html)

> Это (что?) интересно.

Краткие прилагательные не употребляются после **-это**/**-значит**. Синтаксический вопрос после этих слов всегда один и тот же: кто?/что?. Морфологический вопрос может быть разным.

Сравните:

> Игра в мяч (какова?) веселА.      // Краткое прилагательное

> Игра в мяч - это (какова?) веселА.      // Ошибка

> Игра в мяч - это (что?) вЕсело. // Синтаксический вопрос "что?". Морфологический вопрос не имеет значения, но это не "каково?" ибо см ошибку в предыдущей строке.

Следующая фраза вполне корректна грамматически, хотя семантически избыточна:

> Это - это вЕсело // наречие, синтаксический вопрос (что?)

Теперь просто опускаем связку **-это** и не меняя грамматики и смысла получаем:

> Это вЕсело // что?

Если же мы меняем грамматику, смысл и ударение, то получаем фразу:

> Это веселО // каково?